# "Training on" or "Training about"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions

What preposition usually follows the verb "training"? Given a particular piece of software on which the staff is going to receive training in the boardroom, should one use "training on", "training about", or some other preposition? Or to use an example:

> There will be a session for staff training **about** [Software title].
>
> There will be a session for staff training **on** [Software title].

Answer (score 8):

"Training" and prepositions.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/train starting from here, and http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/train_2 here:

- to train for - To archive something. "To train for your first ride", "To train for promotion"
- to train to - In order to do; to able to do. "They trained them to run very fast"
- to train to be - To be able to be. "He trained to be stronger"
- to train in - To be better in something. "She trained in pediatrics", "I don't have any training in interior decorating"
- to train as - To be taught through sustained practice and instruction. "He trained as a plumber" (http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/training)
- to train on - To educate someone in the use of something. "We trained him on the high diving board" (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/train+on)
- to train about - *Rare find. "Teaching doctors in training about management and leadership" (http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d5672), "Get training about how to use GIS" (http://www.in.gov/gis/2350.htm).
- [transitive] Train something (around/along/up, etc.) to make a plant grow in a particular direction. "Roses had been trained around the door"

Comment: +1 for linking to http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/ which has a section to the word origin --- I was looking for whether train (the vehicle) and training (the learning process) had the same origin

Answer (score 2):

I ran a quick series of Google searches for "training about Photoshop," "training for Photoshop," "training in Photoshop," "training on Photoshop," and "training with Photoshop." The results are meaningful only insofar as they provide a snapshot of the relative popularity of "training about," "training for," "training in," "training on," and "training with" this particular software program. But despite their limited relevance, the results are interesting.

In order, from most matches to fewest matches (with number of matches in parentheses), the results were as follows: "training in Photoshop" (128,000), "training with Photoshop" (107,000), "training for Photoshop" (71,900), "training on Photoshop" (15,400), "training about Photoshop" (2,700). Those results suggest that "training in," "training with," and "training for" a particular software program have solid support; "training on" a particular software program is somewhat less popular; and "training about" a particular software program is rather rare.

I also ran a series of other simple Google searches in which I replaced "Photoshop" successively with "software," "the iPad," and "hardware." In every case, "training about" lagged behind the other four options—usually by a very large margin.

At the computer magazines where I've worked, the wording I heard most frequently was "training in [name of software program or operating system]" and "training on [name of computer or other hardware device]." Nevertheless, I wouldn't say that using any of the first four options ("training for," "training in," "training on," and "training with") in connection with either a particular software program or a particular piece of hardware constitutes a serious mistake. But I would not use the phrase "training about" in connection with software or hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Any of several prepositions could be used with "training" in the context you describe. "About", "on", "in", and "over" might all be used to good effect, the differences between them more a matter of nuance in the detail provided in the training. "About" and "over" suggest a general course of broad applicability, such as the typical employee would take on use of the phone or fire alarm systems, while "in" suggests a more detailed course such as might be needed by the person who maintains the fire alarms, or serves as telephone operator.

Comment: Anyway,that sentence is correct,right?we can use on,about,over or in according to the context.Thanks.training on + training subject.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "staff training for $software" or "staff training regarding $software" where the first one may be a bit more direct (only software training, not policies and whatever surrounding it), but I'm not a native speaker so I can't say for sure. Prepositions are a notoriously thorny thing to grasp in almost any language (European, at least), because they rarely make sense and oftentimes there are disagreements even between native speakers on what prepositions should be used, so in that sense you may want to skip the preposition completely if you feel unsure:

*"Staff Training: $software"*

I would *not* use "training about", it sounds unnatural. You may want to try googling your phrases (don't forget the quotes, to search for the entire phrase) and see if people actually use it. Googling for "training about" gives nothing, because noone phrases it like that.

Comment: So training on+ subject is fine,right/

Comment: Ask Google. It seems to be used, I found results like "Scottish Training on Drugs and Alcohol (STRADA)", "Training on 'Leadership communication and political participation' for NC" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have been involved in technical training since 1958. The preposition between the verb and the craft that is being taught has always been "in". Training in gunnery; training in lathework; training in wordprocessing. Other prepositions for this purpose are less elegant.

Answer (score -3):

"There will be a session of $software training for staff" feels like a natural sounding alternative to me.