# Should I use "training in" or "training about"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentences is correctly phrased: "I have been actively involved in training students about Ground Operations", or
"I have been actively involved in training students in Ground Operations"?

Comment: 'Training in' would be the standard thing to say. Here's a near-duplicate; it answers yours, too: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182623/training-on-or-training-about

Comment: @Shule That answer is useful, but there's something interesting about following "training" with a direct object ("students") that makes the preposition more flexible.

Comment: If you have done the training yourself, can you say *trained students* without the vague introduction of *actively involved in*? And who else but students would you train?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should use **training students in**, but the answer isn't as definite as in this [Stack Exchange question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182623/training-on-or-training-about) because of the presence of the direct object.

As an illustration, it is difficult to find the collocation *training about*, which suggests that it is an error. However, **training students about ...** occurs in fairly formal contexts. For example, note [this newsletter entry](https://www.apa.org/pi/disability/resources/publications/newsletter/2014/07/clinical-psychology) by Megan Carlos, "Training clinical psychology students with disabilities in psychological testing and assessment." The title uses "training clinical psychology students with disabilities **in**" something. However, the use with *about* occurs in-text:

> The range of anecdotal experiences described by trainees with disabilities, in combination with an absence of literature available on test examiners with disabilities, suggests that there is a lack of clarity among psychologists involved in **training students about what constitutes reasonable accommodations for trainees with disabilities** with regards to psychological testing in coursework, practicum placements and internships.

The uses are also mixed in an academic article, "[Intimate Partner Violence in the Medical School Curriculum: Approaches and Lessons Learned](https://journalofethics.ama-assn.org/article/intimate-partner-violence-medical-school-curriculum-approaches-and-lessons-learned/2009-02)." *Training in* appears first:

> Not surprisingly, research has shown that physicians who receive specific **training in IPV** are more likely to screen for it ...

A few paragraphs later, *training students about* appears:

> The patient population and the medical student body are among the most racially and ethnically diverse in the nation, which creates both opportunities and hurdles to **training students about IPV**.

From both of these examples, *train(ing) ... about* operates in a sense close to the verb *inform(ing) ... about*, [where the object of the preposition denotes an information-based item](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/inform): "what constitutes reasonable accommodations" and "IPV." A *skill* or a *larger field of knowledge* ("psychological testing," "IPV" as something *physicians* identify) would be less likely to follow *training ... about*, since *about* following verbs of conveying learning does not ordinarily do that. (I can't find examples of broader usage, which is a weak form of support but the best I have.) So *training ... in* has more versatility and can be used with a gerund like so:

> "[A Novel Approach to Training Students in Delivering Evidence-Based Obesity Treatment](https://www.stfm.org/FamilyMedicine/Vol47Issue5/Brown378)"

"Delivering evidence-based obesity treatment" is a larger skill, and 24,000 results in Google have the exact phrase "[training students in delivering](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22training%20students%20in%20delivering%22)." As of this writing, no results exist for "training students about delivering," suggesting that the gerund (suggesting action or skill) may not agree with *training ... about*.

In overall usage, a very rough measure with Google search results suggests that "training students about" (with [about 100,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22training%20students%20about%22)) is ten times less likely to occur than "training students in" (with [about 1,000,000 results](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22training%20students%20in%22)). That also provides support for *training students about* being more specialized in use. It'd take a lot more research to fully describe what's going on here.

Finally, in your case, what you use depends on your precise intent. In the general case,

> I have been actively involved in **training students in Ground Operations,**

there is no issue or restriction to think about. In the specific case,

> I have been actively involved in **training students about Ground Operations,**

there are several factors to consider, and overall *Ground Operations* can only operate as a piece of information, not as a larger skill or field of practice. I would not use *about* if I were educating people in how to conduct ground operations, but I might use *about* if I were telling civilians or an elementary school class about what ground operations is.